# Intl.DateTimeFormat does not bother about '2-digit' or 'numeric'

Tags: javascript, datetime, time, datetime-format, intl

I want to use IntlDateTimeFormat to provide leading zeros.
My code is:

```js
const timeFormatter = Intl.DateTimeFormat(undefined,{minute: '2-digit'});

const date = new Date();
date.setMinutes(4);

console.log(timeFormatter.format(date));  // PRINTS: 4 and not 04
```

However, when I add `second: '2-digit'` to the options object. Then it works fine, but also prints seconds (Yes, I can remove it using replace).

What's the difference between '2-digit' and 'numeric' then?

I am ignoring padStart, as of now.

I tried to change the configuration back to 'numeric' instead of '2-digit'. There seems no difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the difference between '2-digit' and 'numeric'?

Not all options apply to all serializations for all option combinations.

For (only) the formats **which are implemented to support serializing [2-digit minutes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat#minute) in a given language**, that setting controls whether or not the minutes will be represented as 1 or 2 digits.

Formatted strings produced by [`Intl.DateTimeFormat.prototype.format()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/format) are *both* implementation- and language-dependent, so they are not appropriate for producing strings which need to match exact schemas.

Other combinations might also produce strings you don't expect:

```js
const date = new Date(2023, 4, 10, 16, 4, 8);

const printFormatted = (opts) => console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat(undefined, opts).format(date));

printFormatted({ minute: "2-digit" });
printFormatted({ minute: "numeric", second: "numeric" });
printFormatted({ minute: "numeric", weekday: "long" });
printFormatted({ minute: "2-digit", weekday: "long" });
```

Based on the example code in your question: if your goal is to convert a 1-digit or 2-digit integer to a 2-digit string with a leading 0, then [`String.prototype.padStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) is the idiomatic solution:

```js
const date = new Date(2023, 4, 10, 16, 4, 8);

const zeroFour = String(date.getMinutes()).padStart(2, "0");

console.log(zeroFour); // 04
```

Comment: "*… they are not appropriate for producing strings which need to match exact schemas…*" should be in bold capitals. ;-)